# What does a : -> b mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement a dictionary in Haskell and I see that the data type must be

```
data Rel a b = a :-> b
```

but I don't see what it means, I think it's the same thing as key-value or similar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like `:->` is just a fancy constructor name:

```
Prelude> data Rel a b = a :-> b
Prelude> :t (5 :-> 6)
(5 :-> 6) :: (Num a, Num b) => Rel a b
```

In this code, `5 :-> 6` produces a `Rel` value.

One could've used `data Rel a b = a :-% b` instead, for example, where `:-%` would be the constructor name.

Comment: One could also have used a non-operator such as `data Rel a b = MkRel a b` and `:t MkRel 5 6`.

Answer (score 6):

This declaration *defines* what `:->` means: it's an infix data constructor.

```
> :t 3 :-> 5
3 :-> 5 :: (Num a, Num b) => Rel a b
```

The definition could also have been written

```
data Rel a b = (:->) a b
```

in the usual prefix notation.

It's a lot like an ordinary infix operator, except an infix data constructor *must* start with a `:`. You may have seen the pseudo-Haskell definition of the list type:

```
data [] a = [] | a : [a]
```

which defines `(:)` as the infix data constructor for non-empty lists.